# Remove title bar in MATLAB gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

How can I remove `title bar` in `MATLAB GUI` ? I want a blank window without any `title bar` `close`, `maximize` and `minimize`buttons.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it's explicitly against the MATLAB license agreement for you to do this, as it removes a logo from an application window.

Comment: Thank you Sam about this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that works for both OSX and Windows:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');  %# A sample image to display
jimg = im2java(img);
frame = javax.swing.JFrame;
frame.setUndecorated(true);
icon = javax.swing.ImageIcon(jimg);
label = javax.swing.JLabel(icon);
frame.getContentPane.add(label);
frame.pack;
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');  %# Get the screen size from the root object
frame.setSize(screenSize(3),screenSize(4));
frame.setLocation(0,0);
frame.show;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this code maximize (full screen) the window. How can i only remove title bar? + adding an image to window

Comment: @user2991243 the code to add the image is given icon = javax.swing.ImageIcon(jimg);
label = javax.swing.JLabel(icon);
frame.getContentPane.add(label);
frame.pack;